Data doesn't show on template - django
I have a chat app but it seems that i have a few mistakes which i don't know what is.
Users can not see their chat history and their messages in the app.
When Users write their messages on a specific form, I can see their messages on Django admin and that means the messages send successfully.
But the problem starts in views.py, I tried a lot to address the template on chat history feed but when you run the app there is no response except:
No chat history available.

How can I fix this?
We have models on models.py:


# Main Imports
# Django Imports

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

# My Module Imports

from authentication.models import BasicUserProfile

# Chat

# ---------

class Chat(models.Model):
creation_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
content = models.TextField()
sender = models.ForeignKey(
BasicUserProfile,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,
blank=True,
null=True,
related_name="sender"
)
reciever = models.ForeignKey(
BasicUserProfile,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,
blank=True,
null=True,
related_name="reciever"
)

def __str__(self):
    return "chat: " + str(self.sender)

`
and views.py:
 \`def chat_single(request, username):
 """ in this page users can chat with each other """

# admin user session pop
# admin user session pop
# Deleting any sessions regarding top-tier type of users

# Get the current users
current_basic_user = get_current_user(request, User, ObjectDoesNotExist)

current_basic_user_profile = get_current_user_profile(
    request,
    User,
    BasicUserProfile,
    ObjectDoesNotExist
)



# Topics to follow
topics_to_follow = get_topics_to_follow(Topic, ObjectDoesNotExist, random)

# Who to follow box cells
who_to_follow = get_who_to_follow(
    BasicUserProfile
)

# Get the current followings
try:
    current_followings = Follower.objects.filter(
        follower=current_basic_user_profile
    )
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    current_followings = None

# Get the current text reciever (user)
try:
    current_reciever_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    current_reciever_user = None

try:
    current_reciever = BasicUserProfile.objects.get(
        user=current_reciever_user
    )
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    current_reciever = None

if current_reciever_user == None:
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")


# Getting the chat history feed
chat_history_feed = []

try:
    chat_records_self = Chat.objects.filter(
    sender=current_basic_user_profile,
    reciever=current_reciever

    )
    chat_records_reciever = Chat.objects.filter(
    sender=current_reciever,
    reciever=current_basic_user_profile

    )
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    chat_records_self = None
    chat_records_reciever= None

print(chat_history_feed)

# Chat text from processing
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get("chat_send_submit_btn"):
        chat_content = request.POST.get("chat_content")
        new_message = Chat(
        content=chat_content,
        sender=current_basic_user_profile,
        reciever=current_reciever,
        )
        new_message.save()
        chat_history_feed.append(chat_content)  # Adding the message to chat history feed
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/chat/"+current_reciever_user.username+"/")
    
data = {
    "current_basic_user": current_basic_user,
    "current_basic_user_profile": current_basic_user_profile,
    "who_to_follow": who_to_follow,
    "topics_to_follow": topics_to_follow,
    "current_followings": current_followings,
    "current_reciever": current_reciever,
}

if current_basic_user == None:
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/auth/login/")
else:
    return render(request, "chat/single.html", data)


data = {
    "current_basic_user": current_basic_user,
    "current_basic_user_profile": current_basic_user_profile,
    "who_to_follow": who_to_follow,
    "topics_to_follow": topics_to_follow,
    "current_followings": current_followings,
    "current_reciever": current_reciever,
}

if current_basic_user == None:
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/auth/login/")
else:
    return render(request, "chat/single.html", data)`

template.html:


`<div id="chat-right-middle-box">
  <div id="chat-self-box">
    <ul>
      {% for chat_record in chats %}
          <li>
              <strong>{{ chat_record.sender }}</strong>: {{ chat_record.content }}
          </li>
      {% empty %}
          <li>No chat history available.</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="clear-float"></div>

  <div id="chat-other-box">
    <ul>
      {% for chat_record in chat_single %}
          <li>
              <strong>{{ chat_record.content }}</strong>: {{ chat_record }}
          </li>
      {% empty %}
          <li>No chat history available.</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  </div>`

the problem starts from here, where users should be able to see their messages on chat_history_feed but when we open the app we just have that response: No chat history available.
Warn: When Users type something on the specific form and submit, I can see their messages on django-admin
Thank you!
I tried to address the chat_history_feed on template, so Users can see history of their messages.
but i got the response that i've told before.

You are not passing in chats in your view context to render in the template here: {% for chat_record in chats %}, you also are not passing the context for chat_single here: {% for chat_record in chat_single %}...you must pass template variables into the context to use them in a template (or build template variables using other variables but that is out of scope of this question)...this is why you see "No chat history available"

Additionally UX-wise...if you are building a chat-like app with live updates, obviously get this working first, but you should look at Django-Channels for websockets. Using that you can update the chat area on database entry universally for all users...but that is a future look

You say the template is named template.html, but there is no render call to a template of that name anywhere in the code you posted.

didn't work :( @ViaTech

Hmm...@JohnGordon is right, I missed that initially. It appears you are not calling your "correct" template (as well as the other issue I stated with not passing in vars). Can you show your template names to be sure this isn't an issue? Based on your code it looks like you are rendering chat/single.html instead of the name you provided in the post template.html. I've actually run into issues like this before when I am copying functionality and forget to update the template correctly (actually kinda hard to debug), if we can also see your directory structure I'm sure this can be resolved
